# getsymbols command

Tags: stata

I have Stata 13 MP and I try to run the following command:

```
getsymbols AAPL MSFT GE GM WMT, fm(1) fd(1) fy(2010) lm(12) ld(31) ly(2023)frequency(m) price(adjclose) clear
```

I get the following message:

```
<istmt>:  3499  m_getsymbol() not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You likely haven't installed the Mata library needed to run this command.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-install the getsymbols package from ssc:

ssc install getsymbols, all replace